# Shortcut for window fullscreen on MATE?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, tiling

Is there any way to stretch a window using a keyboard shortcut to fullscreen or to the left half or right half within the MATE desktop environment? I am missing `Super` + `Up` or `Super` + `Left`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these shortcuts are shown in *MATE Control Center* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* (`mate-keybinding-properties`) in *Window Management* section:

> [image: MATE Keyboard Shortcuts]

You can define or redefine them here:

- *Toggle fullscreen mode* - you may want to define <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> here or other;
- *Toggle maximization state* - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>;
- *Tile window to east (right) side of screen* - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP Right</kbd> (`KP` means keypad - button from numpad when `NumLock` is active)
- *Tile window to west (left) side of screen* - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP Left</kbd>
- other tiling options are available with

  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_Begin</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_Page_Up</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_Home</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_Page_Down</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_End</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_Up</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP_Down</kbd>